# Update specific task of page in OneNote using API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api, microsoft-graph-onenote

I am working on OneNote API where I want to update a specific task. But I didn't find any way/API to do that.

Here is what I go to so far using `graph API`

[image: graph API]

I need to update/replace the whole `div` which isn't the use case. I might have other text there. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think the body of your PATCH request is correct. If you want to update a particular div you will need to replace the entire contents. So 'action':'replace' makes sense but 'position':'after' doesn't. If you have other text inside the div you must include that in the new content as well.

Comment: What would be the best solution?

Comment: It looks like you want to append your content to  a current div. I guess you retrieve the target div with includeIDs=true and then take the current contents and add your new content before replacing the entire div.

Comment: I got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had `position` in the patch request payload which should not have.

[image]

After removing `postion` it's working for a single task to make it `completed` or `uncompleted` and even change the text of the task.